# Is there a way to Save As a Google Doc in PDF format And in Docx format- but directly to the Drive folder that the gdoc fil is placed in?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to Save As a Google Doc in PDF format And in Docx format- but directly to the Drive folder that the gdoc fil is placed in??  Instead of downloading the file and putting it back in Gdrive folder ??

Google app script solution.